# QComboBox.currentText() -- PySide vs PyQt4

Tags: pyqt4, pyside, qstring, qcombobox

I've got a python script using PySide and it works fine.
But then I thought to check if it gonna work with PyQt4.
And after changing the import strings to PyQt4, things went wrong.
The error points to the subject, as follows:

```
  File "./my_file.py", line 93, in showit
    curr_query = '.'.join(curr_query)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, QString found
```

From the docs I can see that PySide subject method returns 'unicode' string,
but the PyQt4 one returns QString object. 
Playing with the **str**(), str() etc did not seem to do the job.
Here's the function code:

```
def showit(self, idx):
    curr_query = []
    for i in xrange(idx+1):
>>    x = self.combo[i].currentText()
>>    if x:
            curr_query.append(x)
        else:
            break
    curr_query = '.'.join(curr_query)
```

This reads text of a set of QCombobox'es to build up a dot-sepated string presentation that I use later.
The marked '>>' lines is where the issue occurs - the 'x' object is never an empty string, suddenly, as it was while using PySide library. But it is expected to be empty, if there's an empty self.combo[i] .

I've searched the SO archive and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058492/pyqt-vs-pyside-comparison#comment4582433_2058548) but not able to use it.
Please advice how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your `x` values to a string of sorts.  Something like

```
curr_query.append(str(x))
```

should do the trick.

Comment: The problem is that 'x' is never empty string, so this code doesn't even get to work. The if condition is at focus, cuz for PyQt4 it is QString, and for PySide it's a unicode string. And somehow, "if x:" for QString is never true.

Comment: It seems the problem is more general for me, I've done more testing here and noticed that this behaviour is common for my other procedures that read from QComboBox.currentText(). It's related to casting the text value to str(), that's right.